# For loop and add a new column to dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataset called tweet_new, and tweet content is in "text" column in this dataset.

I will perform a sentiment analysis on each tweet content using get_avg_sentiment function below:

```
get_avg_sentiment = function(tweet){sentiment = sentiment_by(tweet)}
```

I want to use a for loop to run the function on all tweets in database, and then add a new column to store the result sentiment result. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop for this. R supports (and is optimized for) vectorized operations, so you should be able to do `tweet_new$sentiment <- get_avg_sentiment(tweet_new$text)`

Comment: sentiment_by could only apply to one tweet each time. When I try, get_avg_sentiment(tweet_new$text), I got error in UseMethod("sentiment_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'sentiment_by' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: Sounds like `tweet_new$text` is stored as `factor` rather than `character`. Try first converting to `as.character()`